# Dashcode List - OnClick

Tags: javascript, dashcode

I have created a project in Dashcode, inserted a List control, enabled a dynamic list, created a JSON object and associated it with the control. The code looks like this ...

```
var stations = {

    _rowData: ["Mitchelton", "Gaythorne", "Albion", "Central", 
    "Burpengary", "Petrie", "Morayfield", "Caboolture", "Ferny Grove"],

    numberOfRows: function() { return this._rowData.length; },

    prepareRow: function(rowElement, rowIndex, templateElements) {
        if (templateElements.label) {
            templateElements.label.innerText = this._rowData[rowIndex];
        }
        rowElement.onclick = function(event) { alert("Row "+rowIndex); };
    }
```

As you can see when an item is selected it will print the rowIndex, but I would like to display the actual value at that index.

Unfortunately this (for example) "this._rowData[2]" doesnt work, it doesn't seem to be able to find the "_rowData" object.

Comment: By the way, you're not actually creating a *JSON* object—you're creating a normal JavaScript object. JSON just happens to use JavaScript object notation for its syntax (hence the name: "JavaScriptObjectNotation").

Comment: no worries :) see, we learn something new every day :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
prepareRow: function(rowElement, rowIndex, templateElements) {
    if (templateElements.label) {
        templateElements.label.innerText = this._rowData[rowIndex];
    }

    var _this = this;
    rowElement.onclick = function(event) { alert(_this._rowData[2]); };
}
```

The problem is that within the `rowElement.onclick` event handler, `this` refers to the DOM element `rowElement`, not your `stations` object. We fix the problem by creating a variable (I've named it `_this`, but you can call it whatever you want) that points to the `stations` object and then using this variable whenever we want to access the `stations` object inside the event handler.

See the following two articles for more information on the `this` keyword:

- http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html
- http://www.alistapart.com/articles/getoutbindingsituations

Comment: sweet, thanks a bunch :) This kinda explains some code I saw earlier (while googling for an answer for this problem) where someone had put "var self = this" ... I thought they had gone nuts or something, but now I see what they were doing :)

Comment: Yes! If you look at the AppleClasses, you'll notice they also create a variable "self" in situations like this...